# How can a constant flux machine store varying amounts of energy in its magnetic field?

Tags: transformer, magnetic-flux

A transformer is said to be a constant (i.e., constant RMS) flux machine. If load currents increase, how can the transformer store more energy in its magnetic field if it cannot accomodate a higher RMS value for the magnetic flux?

Comment: A transformer does not need to "store" more energy in order to transmit more power. Even as primary and secondary currents increase, the net flux in the core remains more-or-less constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magnetic flux in a regular transformer is used **only** to induce a voltage across the secondary terminals. So, if you have a fairly ideal 1:1 transformer (for example) and you apply 100 volts 50 Hz to the primary, you can expect to see 100 volts induced on the secondary. The rate of change of flux that the primary generates AND the 1:1 turns ratio ensure that there has to be the same voltage induced on the secondary winding.

Imagine the problems that would arise if load currents (and their associated fluxes) meddled with this previously described induction process. A transformer would become useless in one extreme or destroy the universe in the other extreme.

And, the reason why load currents don't affect the induction process is that the ampere-turns in the secondary winding are totally cancelled by the ampere-turns (due to the secondary load current) in the primary winding.

This is why we say that a transformer is a constant flux device. OK, what we really mean is the the **RMS** flux is constant for any given frequency and applied primary voltage.

> *how can the transformer store more energy in its magnetic field if it
> cannot accommodate a higher RMS value for the magnetic flux?*

Hopefully you can now see that it doesn't need to; it is sufficient that the primary winding produces an alternating magnetic field that remains constant in amplitude. This flux is due to the current that flows into the primary when the secondary is unused and, load currents are an additional current that play no role in the induction process.

Answer (score 1):

A transformer* transmits power instantaneously between primary and secondary; any energy storage is only incidental, a non-ideal aspect.

*In the meaning of a transformer as an ideal one, i.e. small enough leakage inductance to ignore (or at worst, model as a series inductance), and large enough magnetizing inductance to ignore (I<sub>mag</sub> a small fraction of I<sub>load</sub>).

This contrasts with how we might define a *coupled inductor*, where the primary winding is used to store energy in the magnetizing inductance, which is then released into the secondary path.  This describes a flyback transformer -- which we still call a "transformer" in the more common, less specific sense of: an inductive component with multiple windings.

Note that neither of these definitions are the most common meanings/uses of these words (there is much overlap in commercial or colloquial use) -- hence why I'm carefully outlining these potential definitions.